# How to activate a trigger when a table is read?

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server 2012. Is there a way to have a trigger that is activated when a table/row is read, not modified or deleted?

Comment: trigger only activate upon INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE

Comment: The [SQL Server documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510741(v=sql.110).aspx) makes it clear where triggers can be used. Have you read that documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create such trigger. There [three](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) types of triggers that can be created depending on the events they are listing:

- DML

  > DML triggers execute when a user tries to modify data through a data
  >   manipulation language (DML) event. DML events are INSERT, UPDATE, or
  >   DELETE statements on a table or view.
- DDL

  > DDL triggers execute in response to a variety of data definition
  >   language (DDL) events.
- logon trigger

  > LOGON event that is raised when a user sessions is being established.

End the events the triggers are listing are the following:

- DML

  > INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view
- DDL

  > CREATE, ALTER, DROP, GRANT, DENY, REVOKE or UPDATE statement
- logon trigger

  > LOGON event

You can check all DDL events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events).

Answer (score 2):

If the need is to know ,who accessed the table, you can use

1.SQLSERVER Audit
2.Extended events

I would go with extended events as it is light weight and also provides an option to store the log to file for later analysis..If you are looking for Audit,then you can also check below link:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sreekarm/2009/01/05/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/